# Access Denied when trying to Edit Bucket policy

Tags: amazon-s3

According to the ACL I should be able to write the bucket permissions because when I go to "My Security Credentials" I can verify that my Canonical User ID is the one that appear as the one that should be able to edit the bucket permissions:

[image]

Yet everytime I try to edit the bucket permissions I get the following "access denied" message:

[image]

I don't understand why is this happening, I made the policy in the [generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) with the following options:

[image]

And I'm getting the ARN from here:

[image]

So according to me everything should be correct ... What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: The same "access denied" message appear if I try to make it public or edit other properties...

Comment: Did you figure this problem out?

Comment: @Noitidart Nope, the only way I was able to edit the bucket policy was by going to the public access settings of the bucket and then [unchecking "Block new public bucket policies"](https://i.imgur.com/LHyuK1Q.png), but I doubt that's the expected beehavior or maybe AWS changed it, because I was watching a course where the teacher didn't have to do that to edit the bucket's policy.

Comment: Thanks OiciTrap I appreciate it.